# Select Query Working but insert Query isn't

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(REQUEST_ID) AS REQUEST_ID FROM TBL_REQUEST;";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        echo "alert('DataBase Error');";
    }
    else{
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $newReqId=$row['REQUEST_ID']+1;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_REQUEST VALUES(".$newReqId.",\'ISSUE\',\'Test\',\'Test\',\'NSNS05\',1);";
    $newsql = $sql;
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $newsql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        echo "alert('Not Inserted '+assoc_id+' ".$stmt." '+' ".$newsql." ');";
    }
    else{
        echo "alert('Inserted '+assoc_id+' ".$stmt."');";
    }

?>
```

in this above code i have used 2 SQL statements the first one is a select statement which works fine and fetches data from the table, but when i execute the Insert on the same table its not working...

```
INSERT INTO TBL_REQUEST VALUES(4016,'ISSUE','Test','Test','NSNS05',1);
```

thats the string which is

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: remove the `\` from your php code query. no meaning of that.

Comment: You haven't specified Column names in Insert Query. Go through this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Why are you manually incrementing the ID column? You should use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) to auto-increment.

Comment: remove \ no need to used in your query string syntax...

Comment: \ is needed because php is recognizing ' as end of string... but ' has to be part of the string

Answer (score 0):

why are using `""` between `""` you should `' '` for `$newReqId`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_REQUEST VALUES(".$newReqId.",\'ISSUE\',\'Test\',\'Test\',\'NSNS05\',1);";
```

Comment: use this '$newReqId'

Comment: Your answer is not only not an answer, but also wrong. You should read and learn a bit more about the basics of PHP.

Comment: i dont think thats a solution because... when i display the string in alert box its showing correctly.